# Not expected parameter in function while linking stage

Tags: c++

I have a function which has signature :

```
int alarmCreate(const std::string& familyCode,  std::vector<std::pair<std::string,boost::any> >& alarmparameters, const std::string& description);
```

As can be seen , it has three parameters; string,vector,string.

But when I am building my project I am getting a error  :

/root/projects/test/test.cpp:152: undefined reference to

```
 redisHandler::alarmCreate(std::string const&, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, boost::any>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, boost::any> > >&, std::string const&)
```

I see a fourth parameter with type std::allocator , I can't understand where it is coming from.

Do you guys have any idea , why there is a 4th parameter in my function ?

EDIT :: It turns out there is 3 parameters. But I am still curious why I am getting the error. This function is in a static library. When I search this library with "nm" I see my func exists(can be seen below) .  Do you have any idea what may I missing?

[root@ ~/projects/test/test]# nm ../../lib/libredis.a  |grep alarmCreate

000000000000073c T_ZN12redisHandler11alarmCreateERKSsRSt6vectorISt4pairISsN5boost3anyEESaIS6_EES1_

Comment: "I see a fourth parameter". No you don't. Count angle brackets, carefully.

Comment: did you define and link the function?

Answer (score 4):

It is a template parameter of the `vector`. Every standard container have an allocator, and it has a default value so you don't need to bother about this one.

Your method may have been declared but it is not defined.

Comment: Thanks alot for comment , I known containers contain allocator , I just didn't cound brackets well.